# Sharing an image on android oreo doesn't work but with nougat work

Tags: android, android-intent, share, android-fileprovider

Here there is the code, I don't understand why it doesn't work on oreo.

```
 Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(mChart);
            try {
                File file = new File(getActivity().getExternalCacheDir(), "logicchip.png");
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
                file.setReadable(true, false);
                final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                intent.setType("image/png");
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Check this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed